# I just lost the ability to talk in chat!

Tags: bug, status-completed

For some reason, chat seems to think I don't have the 20 rep required to chat.  Not sure how it happened, but I was talking just fine prior to whatever it is that happened.

[image]

I'm using the latest version of Firefox, if that has anything to do with it.  Closing Firefox and re-opening didn't help.

I don't think I got banned or anything; I still have my rep.  Did I get flagged or something?

Comment: Checking your chat profile, it seems like the system thinks you have zero reputation. Try re-associating with another site temporarily?

Comment: Changed it to SO, and I get a reputation number now, but I still can't talk.

Comment: ...and now it's back.  Huh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some account associations got messed up.  This wasn't limited to just me.

[Chat claims my reputation is much lower than it really is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146000/chat-bug-you-need-20-rep-to-chat)

Anyways, everything seems to be working fine again.